# class can't have main() in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner of Scala.

In Calulator.scala file

```
class Calulator {
    var brand: String ="HP"
    def add(m:Int, n:Int):Int = m+n 
}
```

In CalculatorTest.scala file

```
object CalulatorTest  {
    def main(args:Array[String]) {
        val cal = new Calulator
        println(cal.add(1,2))
    }
}
```

Compile two scala files and run CalculatorTest. This works.

My question is can I make them as one scala file like Java?

In Calulator.scala file

```
class Calulator {
    var brand: String ="HP"
    def add(m:Int, n:Int):Int = m+n 

    def main(args:Array[String]) {
        val cal = new Calulator
        println(cal.add(1,2))
    }
}
```

This doesn't work !!! 
I googled it and looks like main() should be in object.

Is there a way to put them in one file to run main()?

Comment: What's wrong with just putting the two in one file?

Comment: Java fallacy. You can put as much code as you would like into a single file, the scala compiler doesn't care.

Comment: Well... the thing is that you need your `main` method to be static. And Scala does not allow static members in class. Scala is a whole new language, so it will have things which are totally different from Java.

Answer (score 4):

To put them in one file use the concept of the 'Companion Object'.

The class and companion object must be in the same file and share the same name.

```
class Calculator {
  var brand: String = "HP"

  def add(m: Int, n: Int): Int = m + n
}

object Calculator {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val cal = new Calculator
    println(cal.add(1,2))
  }
}
```

Further reading: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html

Comment: @user2761895 - in addition to this great answer I'd like to say, basically--get used to the idea of using companion objects a _lot_ in Scala. They are _the_ place to put static stuff associated with your classes. In fact, if you ever find yourself creating an instance member in a class, and the value doesn't depend on the instance itself, just put the member in the companion object and make it static.

Comment: Thanks FabFlying and @user2761895. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is **No**
a deeper answer is that the scala compiler refers to an **object** as static and class it refers as regular.

when you want to run Java program your main must be declared as **static** otherwise the JVM will not recognize it as your **program entry point**.

regards the question about is it possible to union both of them ,the answer is not because thats how the scala compiler works.

The compiler would create MyClass$.class for **scala object** and MyClass.class for **scala class** thats why **you should never ever call your class** something like :

```
class MyClass$ {

}
```

because it will override the companion object for MyClass.